# Extracting integer from a for loop iteration in php, twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am currently iterating through arrays of data in php (twig template).

```
{% for subscription in form.peerEventSubscriptions %}
<option value='{{typeDefEvent[0]}}'>-{{ form_label(subscription.eventTypeHumanized) }}-</option>
{% endfor %}
```

The data is just text. Is it possible to also simultaneously get an integer to update the array index:

```
typeDefEvent[i]
```

?
Thanks and remember, this is a twig template.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to introduce another variable here. Quoting [**the docs**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html):

> Inside of a `for` loop block you can access some special variables:

```
Variable        Description
loop.index      The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)
loop.index0     The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed)
loop.revindex   The number of iterations from the end of the loop (1 indexed)
loop.revindex0  The number of iterations from the end of the loop (0 indexed)
loop.first      True if first iteration
loop.last       True if last iteration
loop.length     The number of items in the sequence
loop.parent     The parent context
```

So you can write your template like this:

```
{% for subscription in form.peerEventSubscriptions %}
  <option value='{{typeDefEvent[loop.index0]}}'>-{{ form_label(subscription.eventTypeHumanized) }}-</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set i = 0 %}
   <select name="myPostVar">
{% for subscription in form.peerEventSubscriptions%}
<option value='{{typeDefEvent[i]}}'>-{{ form_label(subscription.eventTypeHumanized) }}-</option>
{% set i = i+1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

basically set and update the iterator in the loop using template tags